# ¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos de una fila entera en Google Sheets usando Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

He creado un trigger que me envía un email cada vez que una hoja de Google Sheets es actualizada.

Pero en el mensaje yo quiero enviar los datos que se escribieron en cada una de las celdas de esa fila que fue actualizada.

En el código que estoy implementando sólo alcanzo a obtener el dato de la celda específica que se actualizó, pero no de la fila completa.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var gSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var cell = gSheet.getDataRange().toString();
    var mEmail='me@gmail.com';
    var mSubject='Nuevo error 404';
    var mBody='Hoja modificada por: '+Session.getActiveUser()+
              '\nDatos: '+gSheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail(mEmail, mSubject, mBody);
}
```

Buscaba entre las posibilidades una especie de método <s>`getActiveRow()`</s>, pero no lo encuentro. ¿Cómo podría obtener todos los valores de esa fila?

---

#### Estado actual del código

Actualmente el código está así:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    Logger.log("e");
    var gSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var cell = gSheet.getDataRange().toString();
    var numFila = e.range.rowStart; 
    var fila = gSheet.getRange(numFila + ":" + numFila);
    var valoresFila = fila.getValues();
    var mEmail='mi-email@gmail.com';
    var mSubject='Nuevo error 404';
    var mBody='Hoja modificada por: '+Session.getActiveUser()+"\nDatos: "+gSheet.getActiveCell().getValue()+" c1: "+valoresFila[1]+" c2: "+valoresFila[2];
    MailApp.sendEmail(mEmail, mSubject, mBody);
}
```

Cuando la hoja se actualiza recibo un email, pero sin datos, algo así:

```
Hoja modificada por: xxxxxx@gmail.com
Datos:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respuesta a la [revisión 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/206728/2), en lo que respecta al código agregado.

El problema son los índices en `valoresFila[1]` y `valoresFila[2]`. Asumiendo que quieres los valores de las celdas de la fila activa que corresponden a las columnas A y B, reemplázalos por `valoresFila[0][0]` y `valoresFila[0][1]`

Lo anterior porque `getValues` devuelve un Array de Arrays y en JavaScript los índices de los Arrays son base 0. El primer índice corresponde a la fila y el segundo a la columna.

---

En relación a la ejecución automática de la función al agregarse una respuesta desde un formulario de Google vinculado a la hoja de cálculo, en lugar de un activador `on Edit` usa un activador `on Form Submit`.

Lo anterior porque los activadores `on Edit` y `on Change`, ya sea simples o instalables sólo se activan por cambios hechos por el usuario que tiene abierta la hoja de cálculo, no por cambios hechos por otra aplicación, como los Formularios de Google, ni por código, ni por actualizaciones automáticas de funciones de hoja de cálculo como `IMPORTRANGE`.

**NOTAS IMPORTANTES**

1. Google Apps Script maneja dos activadores instalables `on Form Submit`, uno para proyectos vinculados a hoja de cálculo y otro para proyectos vinculados a formularios, cada uno con objeto evento con propiedades particulares. Favor de consultar las propiedades de cada uno en [Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).
2. Los activadores como `on Form Submit` y `time-driven` no pueden hacer uso de métodos como `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveCell()` pues estos no emulan al usuario que abre una hoja de cálculo y por ende no existen celda, rango ni selección activos. Sin embargo, en el caso de proyectos vinculados a hoja de cálculo puede usarse sin problema `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`.
3. En el caso de usar un activador `on Form Submit` en un proyecto vinculado a un formulario, si se requiere acceder a la hoja de cálculo vinculada, se podría usar [getDestinationId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getDestinationId()) para obtener el id de la hoja de cálculo vinculada.

Respuesta a la [revisión 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/206728/1)

De la pregunta...

> Buscaba entre las posibilidades una especie de método <s>`getActiveRow()`</s>, pero no lo encuentro. ¿Cómo podría obtener todos los valores de esa fila?

Hay varias formas para obtener todos los valores de una fila.

- Notación de referencias de hoja de cálculo `1:1`
- Usar la notación de array `miArray[i]`
- Usar `getRange(fila, columna, numeroFilas,numeroColumnas)`

Por ejemplo, podemos usar

```
var numFila = e.range.rowStart; 
var fila = gSheet.getRange(numFila + ":" + numFila);
var valoresFila = fila.getValues();
```

donde valoresFila será un array de arrays de 1 x número de columnas de la hoja.

Si quieres limitar a sólo las filas del rango de datos (data range), podemos usar getLastColumn() el cual es ciertas circunstancias podría ser muy lento, o bien usar `gSheet.getDataRange().getValues()[0].length` para obtener el número de columnas de rango de datos.

Comment: Rubén, funciona poniendo el índice `[0]` delante, ahora los datos se muestran. Pero hay algo raro, el email no se envía cuando edito la hoja desde un formulario de Google embebido ligado a ella. Sólo se envía si edito en la hoja directamente alguna fila. ¿Sabrías por qué no se envía al crear una nueva fila en la hoja?

Comment: Creo que @OscarGarcia tiene razón, la pregunta sigue siendo la misma, el objetivo no ha cambiado: recuperar los datos de la fila que fue actualizada. En todo caso puede que surja otro problema, que ya expuse en mi anterior comentario. Si no hay algún error a simple vista investigaría otro tipo de trigger y si no lo consigo lo plantearía en una nueva pregunta. Mi edición no cambia para nada la temática de la pregunta.

Comment: @A._Cedano : los activadores on Edit y on Change, ya sea simple o instalables sólo se activan por cambios hechos por el usuario que tiene abierta la hoja de cálculo, no por cambios hechos por otra aplicación o código, ni por actualizaciones automáticas de funciones como IMPORTRANGE

Comment: ¿Conoces alguna forma de lanzar un trigger en ese contexto: cuando la hoja es editada/actualizada desde un formulario? ¿O habría que hacerlo desde el formulario? Alguna manera tiene que haber...

Comment: @A.Cedano Edité la respuesta para agregar esa información.

Comment: Rubén muchas gracias por tu valiosa respuesta, la cual me ha aclarado varios puntos que no conocía sobre los activadores. La clave para obtener los datos de la fila que fue actualizada era poner un índice `[0]` y luego el índice de cada columna... Dado que con `onFormSubmit` no podía hacer uso de  `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveCell()` me centré en una solución desde el formulario, tomando los valores que eran introducidos en él, para enviar el email con esos datos.

Comment: Muy bien, gracias por hacerlo :) te llevas mi +1, borraré mis comentarios dejar la respuesta limpia.

Answer (score 0):

En las macros, justo debajo de "ejecutar" en el menú, hay un icono de Activadores de proyecto activo.

este te puede ayudar con triggers de a cuerdo a condiciones. te adjunto una imagen de un ejemplo con envío de respuestas de formulario, ejecuta el scrip de la funcion seleccionada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]